# I have stored an array of sections that have an expanded boolean property in my state. How to change the expanded property of a section on click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array of objects saved in my state;

```
const sections = [
    {
        title: "section one",
        expanded: false,
    },
    {
        title: "section two",
        expanded: false,
    },
]
```

I render the sections and I apply onClick handler that executes the toggleSection function which is meant to toggle the expanded property from true to false or vice-versa. How do I go about this?

```
const [sections, setSections] = useState([
    {
        title: "section one",
        expanded: false,
    },
    {
        title: "section two",
        expanded: false,
    },
]);

const toggleSection = (section) => {
    // Toggle the section's expanded property here
}

return (
    <div>
        {sections.map((section) => {
            return <div onClick={() => toggleSection(section)}>{{section.title}}</div>
        });
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.map()` it into a new array, toggling the value in the map callback:

```
setSections([                       // create a new array
  sections.map(s =>                 // for each element in the existing array
    s.title === section.title ?     // if the title matches the one clicked
    {...s, expanded: !s.expanded} : // return an object with the same values but a toggled "expanded"
    s)                              // else return the object as-is
]);
```